# SceneKit - get position in screen coordinate

Tags: glsl, scenekit

How can I get the coordinate of a point in the screen referential from the geometry shader entry point? SceneKit exposes a bunch of matrix transformations and their inverses (https://developer.apple.com/reference/scenekit/scnshadable > Using Inputs Provided by SceneKit) but I could not figure out how to use them...

for instance, in the geometry entry point that's executed in the vertex shader, I've tried:

```
varying vec2 screen_coords;

#pragma body
screen_coords = (u_inverseModelViewProjectionTransform * _geometry.position).xy
```

but that doesn't seem to work :(

To clarify, I'd like `screen_coords` to be in [0, 1] * [0, 1] if the point is in the screen depending on it's exact position, and something else if not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It took me a while, but here it is:

```
vec4 screenPos = u_modelViewProjectionTransform * _geometry.position;
screen_coords = (screenPos.xy / screenPos.w + 1.0) * 0.5;
```

Explanation:
`screenPos` roughly corresponds to the coordinate in screen space. `screenPos.xy / screenPos.w` rescale those coordinate. Then weirdly this gives input [-1, 1] * [-1, 1] so I finally added an offset and scale to get the result in [0, 1] * [0, 1]

Comment: you can have a look at http://www.songho.ca/opengl/gl_projectionmatrix.html which has nice explanations about projection, clip space and normalized device coordinates.

Answer (score 2):

For anyone that stumbles on this in the future, in metal I think you can get the screen coords in the surface shader just by grabbing

```
in.fragmentPosition.xy * scn_frame.inverseResolution.xy
```

[See here for more info](https://gist.github.com/j-j-m/4ebd20e1fdabdfb0f2c2ce86cbeaba45#file-commonprofile-metal-L798)